# Install MongoDB PHP extension on Windows 7

Tags: wampserver, php-extension

I want to install latest MongoDB PHP extenstion(1.2.2) on Windows 7.

(Note: I have tried older version, but they are not working either. 
Also tried Thread safe and non safe versions. OS bit is also correct i.e 64 bit)

Followed links:

http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.windows.php

https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb

I have downloded .dll file and extracted on **ext** directory of Wamp.

(Note: ext directory path is correct - confirmed)

Also added extension=php_mongodb.dll in php.ini

(Note: php.ini file is also the correct one, checked by enabling other ext)

I have also restarted all the services.

But, I don't know why MongoDB extension is not showing on phpinfo().

My system & PHP configuration:

PHP Version: 5.6.15

OS version: Windows 7 64 bit

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Parth Vora

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed the issue after a lot of investigation and trial & error. Issue was difference between bit of the extestion. I was using 64 bit version PHP MongoDB extension as my Windows 7 is 64 bit OS. But my **Wamp** software is 32 bit. So I used 32 bit PHP MongoDB extension and it fixed the issue.

Hope this helps someone.

Thanks